# iOS : unable to connect openfire server in XMPPFramework iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp

I am a beginner of iOS development with XMPP, I develop the iOS XMPP instant messaging app with the tutorial in this link >>> http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-xmpp-setup--mobile-7190

And now I run my project it is not connecting to my openfire server and there are no errors displaying. I heard some developers they had solve relevant problems by "enabling" SSL certificate in iOS client in this link >>> [Unable to connect openfire server using ios client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591553/unable-to-connect-openfire-server-using-ios-client/25061900?noredirect=1#comment38988394_25061900). Do I have to enable it? and how to enable it?

I am using xCode 4.6.3, Mac OS version 10.7.5, iOS 6, Can I post the code of my AppDelegate class for better review? but there is kinda lot of lines of codes.

Thank you.

Comment: I recommend looking at the sample AppDelegate class on the XMPPFramework github project.  In addition to the delegate methods like DidAuthenticate:, it implements DidNotAuthenticate: and other "failure" methods.  Put breakpoints in there to see the errors.  If it never reaches the breakpoints, you likely you don't have AppDelegate setup correctly as an XMPPStream delegate.  If it does, you'll see some XMPP-specific errors that will provide further clues.  I'd be happy to look at your code if you post it, as well.

Comment: I look down the code and I found out I did not have the DidNotAuthenticate method with the following tutorial I had reviewed,  but whenever i put breakpoints into codes it does not go through other methods but only DidAuthenticate.

Comment: it go through these methods :

`- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender {isOpen = YES; NSError *error = nil; [[self xmppStream] authenticateWithPassword:password error:&error];}`

`- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender {[self goOnline];}`

Comment: When you say it's not connecting, do you mean the user you're logging in as never shows as online?  If you're getting as far as calling goOnline with no errors, maybe try implementing delegate methods xmppStream: didSendPresence: and xmppStream: didFailToSendPresence: and put breakpoints in there to see what is coming back from the server when goOnline: tries to set the presence to online.